# PureChat and Mod Deflate

Tags: javascript, apache, .htaccess

I'm working for a web customer who read on a blog that Speed Insights by Google matters. So now they want to have a "high Speed Insights rating because it's good for Google". While I think this is absurd, I don't have a choice but to comply.

Problem is, this customer is using an external javascript script provided by PureChat. This script does not come compressed in any way, leading Speed Insights to scream about how it's not gzipped or deflated.

Is there a way to force PureChat to be served deflated?

Comment: download and serve your own copy, or don't worry about it, since it doesn't really matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with doing that is that PureChat most likely update their scripts quite often. Meaning that if you were to use things like Far-Future headers etc, it could cause issues with the customers cache still running the older version. Which could consist of harmful / exploitable bugs. So as you said, I really would ***NOT*** recommend doing this.

Another problem I find a number of people complain about is Google Analytics affecting their page speed ranking. Even though this is irrelevant, it comes through Google. It can be fixed using a Cron, you could do something similar by ***loading the JavaScript locally***.

See article here: http://diywpblog.com/leverage-browser-cache-optimize-google-analytics/ It describes how to do this, you could use it for PureChat I imagine.